# Python Iterate through characters

Tags: python, string, list, character, loops

I have been trying to pull of median string search for a sequence in the ACGT genome. The problem I have is going to say AAAAAAAA to AAAAAAAC and so forth until I have tried every possible combination.

I've been essentially going brute force at it by creating two lists, one containg A,C,G,T and the other the 8 character sequence, and after each search iterating and swapping characters. The problem is that I don't test all combinations because when two iterate at the same time it jumps a letter.

Is there any way to go AAAAAAAA - AAAAAAAC - AAAAAAAG - AAAAAAAT - AAAAAACA and so forth easily?

Comment: Take a look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) and its combinanatoric generators, [product()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), [permutations()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), [combinations()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) etc. though in this case you will be mostly interested in [product()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) -- see @jamylak's use example.

Comment: see itertools.combinations

http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)

```
itertools.product("ACGT", repeat=8)
```

Comment: @Tauquir you were not the only one late .. :) +1 from me too

Answer (score 2):

As above suggested use itertools,

```
itertools.product("ACGT", repeat=8) # will work in your case.
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [regex inverter](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/invRegex.py) from the pyparsing wiki Examples page, invert this regex: `[ACGT]{8}`.  You can also try the [online inverter at the UtilityMill](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_inverter), but this server will timeout when generating 8-character strings, but I have successfully gotten up to 6 characters within the allowed time.